# Configuring the video speed on Udacity

Tags: video

Ire any way to configure the video speed on Udacity, not just for the current video but for all videos? Each time I change the video speed it gets back to 1 when I go to another video (same for the video quality) through clicking on some link (i.e. not waiting for the next video to load).

[image]